# Controller/Transmitter for Canon 580EXII + Godox AD200

Tags: canon, godox, 580exii

Is there one transmitter like Godox XProC (for Canon 5D MarkIV) to control Canon 580EXII and Godox AD200? If not what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Radio or optical? How much control do you want? To fire in sync? To set power from transmitter? HSS? TTL? something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Godox XProC will work fine, but you will need a Godox X1R-C receiver to attach to the 580EXII hotshoe. This will give you full control (HSS, TTL, ...) over both the AD200 and the speedlite.

Answer (score 1):

Godox has several transmitters in their 2.4 GHz radio system that can trigger and/or control the AD200:

- Flashpoint R2 Pro II-C
- Godox Xpro-C
- Godox X2T-C
- Godox X1T-C
- Flashpoint SPT single-pin transceiver (manual trigger; no TTL/HSS/power control)
- XT32 (manual trigger with HSS/power control)
- XT16 (manual trigger with power control)

The 580EXII, however, does not have radio triggering built-in, and would require an X1R-C receiver to be attached to its foot to be triggered and controlled by the Godox transmitters. And unlike the built-in radio triggers in Godox's own lights, the X1R-C does not support cross-brand TTL, so the 580EXII can only be a TTL/HSS radio slave to a Godox "-C" Canon version trigger on a Canon camera hotshoe.

The ideal way to add an off-camera speedlight to an AD200 would probably be to purchase a Godox speedlight (V1, V860II/TT685, V850II/TT600, etc.) and use that instead, as all the Godox speedlights have built-in radio triggers which simplify setup/packing vs. add-on triggers.